# calculate accuracy using r value

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm using a linear regression model to predict the weather data for one year. Prediction is done using Python's `sklearn` library. The problem is that I need to find the accuracy of the prediction. After a quick internet search I found out that  r^2 is the way to find out the accuracy. I calculated the r value as follows:

```
r value 
 0.0919309031356
Coefficients: 
 [-20.01071429   0.        ]
Residual sum of squares: 19331.78
Variance score: -0.23
```

The problem is that I need to show the accuracy as a percentage. How do I do that? Do I need use a tool to find out the accuracy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this question is more complicated than I think, but why not just

```
r = str((r**2) * 100) + '%'
```

Comment: so according to eg percentage should be 9.19309031356 right

Comment: You need to square the r values first, so more like 0.84%, which is a miserable r-square value in my humble opinion.

Comment: yeah it is a terrible r value. thanks for the help anyway

Answer (score 0):

For regression problems, you can use the following metrics to determine the quality of the fit (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#regression-metrics):

- Mean squared error. Fit is good when the value is as low as possible
- R^2 score. Fit is good when the value is 1 or close to it.

You can also calculate prediction error with: 
     (Actual value - Predicted value)/Actual value.

However, I am not sure if this is a common metric to evaluate a linear regression fit.